# Is JColibri functional yet?

Tags: system

I am building a case-based reasoning system in Colibri Studio, but I keep running into build errors. The documentation is sparse - does anyone else successfully get Colibri Studio to properly build in Eclipse? It is currently in beta 0.9, but it seems to be a little behind beta.

I was thinking that it may be my data, but I don't have a solid way to check this.

Colibri Studio is from GAIA, link here:
http://gaia.fdi.ucm.es/research/colibri/jcolibri

It is supposed to be highly useful, but I have just been frustrated by the whole process. If it is confirmed that the Studio version can successfully build, I can follow up with more questions about how to successfully get it to compile and execute.

Note, this differs from JColibri 2.3, which apparently is a functional Java program that lacks a GUI.